# I accidentally removed my ufw allow rules (ssh and ftp rules) and then logged out of my server, am now locked out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My environment: aws ec2 (VMware Workstation 11) for use as development sandbox environment. it's not crucial, i just have some work i don't want to re do for a client. Is there anyway to change those rules from the outside?

Comment: your question is off topic here, please read Amazon-web-services tag definition.

Comment: I think the question is about changing the ufw rules, which *is* about the OS running on AWS, and is hence on-topic at Super User.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

1. Detach the root volume,
2. Attach it to another instance as a secondary volume,
3. Mount this volume on you OS,
4. Access your firewall rules (most probably on /lib/ufw/user.rules) and change them to allow access. Save.
5. Unmount the volume, detach it
6. Attach it back to your instance and start your instance,

Et voila

Comment: Will he be able to mount it if his volume is encrypted?

Comment: As long as he "owns" the encryption key